# Why i can login without correct password? Why password_verify always returns true?

Tags: php

Why i can login without correct password? I have function for login in my Class user as it stated below, and I had added password_verify, and interesting thing is that whatever password I type in it will always log me in to the system no matter correct or incorrect password.

DB Connection is PDO.
I know that there are a lot of mistakes here, but I'm a beginner.

Can you help me please?

```
public function loginUser($email, $password) {
    try {
        require './database.php';
        switch ($_POST['type']) {
            case 'Buyer':
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM buyer WHERE email=:email");
                break;
            case 'Seller':
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM seller WHERE email=:email");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':email' => $email
        ));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

            if (password_verify($password, $userRow['password'])) {
                switch ($_POST['type']) {
                    case 'Buyer':
                        $_SESSION['type']        = $_POST['type'];
                        $_SESSION['user_id']     = $userRow['buyer_id'];
                        $_SESSION['buyer_name']  = $userRow['buyer_name'];
                        $_SESSION['email']       = $userRow['email'];
                        $_SESSION['password']    = $userRow['password'];
                        $_SESSION['phone']       = $userRow['phone'];
                        $_SESSION['description'] = $userRow['description'];
                        return true;
                        break;
                    case 'Seller':
                        $_SESSION['type']        = $_POST['type'];
                        $_SESSION['user_id']     = $userRow['seller_id'];
                        $_SESSION['buyer_name']  = $userRow['seller_name'];
                        $_SESSION['email']       = $userRow['email'];
                        $_SESSION['password']    = $userRow['password'];
                        $_SESSION['phone']       = $userRow['phone'];
                        $_SESSION['description'] = $userRow['description'];
                        return true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                    return false;

            }
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not always going to return true/false (if you dont send up `type` it will bork, or have no rows), which could be the reason. can you show how your calling the method?

Comment: Ok I am sending my login.php where is shown how I exactly calling a method, which is stated before html code.  `<?php
    require './include/part/header.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

 if($user->loginUser($email,$password))
 {
 $user->redirect('index.php');
 }
 else{
  $error = "Wrong Details !";
 } 
}
 

?>`

Comment: Is there any type of account else? Exclude seller and buyer,?

Comment: No there is only buyer and seller no other types of account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was because I did require './database.php' in function, and database.php had $password = "", and he change every password to empty string.